# PHP buffering error <unknown> in line 0

Tags: php, error-handling, buffering

Would anybody be kind to help me with any possible information on this error? causes? login? where to look/start?

```
 Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in <**Unknown**> on line **0**
```

Example code:

```
function test($b) { return _strrev($b); } 

ob_start("test"); 
echo "123"; 
ob_end_flush();
```

Information:

- This is CentOS 6.7
- This is PHP PHP 5.5.32 (cli)
- This is NOT Wordpress
- This is a simple PHP file with pseudo code (above)
- No caching, no Varnish, no Nginx, no custom headers

Thanks

Comment: Some code would be useful

Comment: I understand your approach, but in my case this is absolutely irrelevant. 
Example: `ob_start("test"); echo "123"; ob_end_flush();`

Comment: So where is your `test` function?

Comment: It is there.. and as I mentioned earlier this is IRRELEVANT to any written code whatsoever. Just try to use anytime of buffering with PHP and this error appears. Maybe I should reform my question.. Did anybody ever see such thing before? :(

Comment: Ok, you obviously know so much more than the rest of us. I will leave you to solve your own problems.

Comment: Yes I do actually; And you should not take things personally in a community powered board. Just say I do not know, or pass-by without asking what appear to be dumb question. Maybe you should ask me if I have PHP installed? I didn't mention that as well.

Comment: And assuming I am a newbie, a whatever you can call me.. PHP should be smarter of a programming language to say Error Unknown on line 0 after all, don't you think so.

Comment: Are you using WordPress? When I google that error message, all the hits seem to be related to WP.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I have just edited the question to keep things tidy and organized as per your request and nature of questions. I am not using WP, and my PHP version is 5.5.32 CLI, thanks

Comment: you can consider that a personal choice. I do not see how your latest few comments contribute towards a solution, not finding a cause for the error itself, sorry.

Comment: Ahhh I just stumbled on something. I coded `function test($b) {
    return str-replace('2', 'XXX', $b);}` NOTE the misspelt `str_replace` and got the exact error you did.

Comment: Does this mean you might have a similiar coding error in your `test` function

Comment: Ooo.. finally we've got something. Can we assume I have some malfunctioning routing inside a buffered block for example?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Please post an answer so I can accept it. The problem was indeed within a buffered block where a queried function was not 'yet' declared. Thank you

Comment: Right, So if you had shown a bit more **actual code** and a slightly less **know it all attitude** in the first place, we might have got here without all this vitriol. Note my first and second comments. And yours re the `test` function: _It is there.. and as I mentioned earlier this is IRRELEVANT_ Not so irrelevant after all

Comment: But I thank you for making me look closer at Output buffering, obviously I incorrectly assumed this was exclusively a web server based concept. I guess we can call this a 50-50 learning experience

Comment: Cheers pal, I am obviously sorry for the attitude.

Comment: Looks like `thetop.center` is down

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant Please edit the question to show the actual `test` function. As the answer shows, this occurs when the callback function gets gets an error, but `return $b;` won't cause that.

Comment: @Barmar, done. I added a non-existing function call as requested to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an effort to make this question of some use to others I will summarise the comments section in the form of an answer.

It turns out that if you make a coding error in the callback function used by `ob_start` it generates this somewhat unhelpful error message

In testing I quite accidentally made a silly error while amending the callback funtion shown by the questioner, I coded

```
<?php
function test($b) {
    return str-replace('2', 'XXX', $b);
}

ob_start("test");
echo "123";
ob_end_flush();
```

Note the misspelling of the `str_replace()` function.

This generated the error

> Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0

So it appears that PHP cannot report runtime errors in an `ob_start` callback funtion. Instead it must default to a generic error along the lines of **Ouch that hurt**

Maybe one of us should report this as a PHP Bug

After some more testing, this error senario produces a meaningful error in PHP 7.0.5

> Notice: Use of undefined constant str - assumed 'str' in tst.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function replace() in tst.php:3

so this may be fixed now, but all previous PHP versions i.e. 5.4 / 5.5 / 5.6 produce the unhelpful error message

Comment: It's not a compilation error, it's a runtime error: **Call to undefined function replace()**

Comment: You should edit the question to show the bad code in the `test` function, so that the error is reproducible.

Comment: @Barmar Tell the questioner to amend his question

Comment: Oops, for some reason I thought the questioner was answering his own question.

Comment: @Barmar I doubt he will, I expect he thinks there is something super sexy and clever in there he does not want to share with the rest of us lesser mortals